# Is there some sort of pool in Java that avoids repeating recents arithmetic operations?

Tags: java, static, floating-point, pool

I have the three following methods:

```
 public static void test1(Point point)
    {
        Handler.doSomething(point.x / 2.0f, point.y / 1.75f);
    }

    public static void test2(Point point)
    {
        Handler.doSomething(point.x / 2.0f, point.y / 0.55f);
    }

    public static void test3(Point point)
    {
        Handler.doSomething(point.x / 2.0f, point.y / 1.25f);
    }
```

Each time one of these methods is called the divisions are performed.
Is there some sort of pool in Java that avoids repeating recents arithmetic operations?
Because if there isn't one, then maybe it would be preferable to save the results the first time so that I can avoid doing this divisions multiple times?
For instance I know for a fact that Java has String pool.

Comment: yes, but I hope you understand that what you describe is not even remotely similar to String pool. one way to get around this is: not have three identical methods. And , not calling three identical methods after one another

Comment: @Stultuske then it would be preferable to make all divisions only one time and have one single method that handles the different coordinates?

Comment: what "different coordinates"? create one method, and pass the coordinates (if need be) as parameters

Comment: Sure but should I store the results of those divisions? Or should I pass them as parameters like this (point.x / 2.0f, point.y / 1.25f);

Comment: why do you need to store anything? that would basically just mean using (and blocking) resources you can leave free

Comment: @DeborahAnn that's something that *you* have to decide. You should measure both solution and decide whether the memory/computation tradoff is worth it. By the way the words you should be looking for are "caching" and "memoization" which represent two different approaches to this kind of problem. But generally, if the computation is not expensive (for example if those methods are not called in a tight loop) you may just leave it as is and let the jvm optimize it if it needs to.

Comment: What is the use case here? You have point, the function is named test, there is some handler which does something - it's unclear what is the goal based on this.

Comment: How many unique combinations of parameters are there?

Comment: @Bohemian 20 more or less.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca one those methods is indeed called sometimes in a tight loop. But generally for 2-3 minutes, every 10-15 minutes.

Comment: @kiner_shah it's not important what that method does. I was simply asking if I should store the results or not.

Comment: The JVM is almost certainly smart enough to optimize this for you.  Don't try to optimize it yourself.

Comment: How expensive are the operations? Would they take more than say 0.01 milliseconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote *Effective Java 3rd Edition* by Josh Bloch, Item 6 ("Avoid creating necessary objects"):

> ... avoiding object creation by maintaining your own object pool is a bad idea unless the objects in the pool are extremely heavyweight [such as a database connection] ...  Generally speaking, however, maintaining your own object pools
> clutters your code, increases memory footprint, and harms performance. Modern
> JVM implementations have highly optimized garbage collectors that easily outperform such object pools on lightweight objects

Arithmetic operations are cheap, even if you do them repeatedly. JVM optimizations may avoid even creating objects in some circumstances.

So, don't try to use an object pool until you have evidence that your program would benefit from one.